# Fastboot "waiting for device"

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader

I have an galaxy s4 i33 that I need to have upgraded for work (or buy a new phone.)

On both windows and Linux I can type "adb reboot bootloader" to open the bootloader.

However, in windows:
-Odin Crashes.
-ADB can only find the device when it is turned on normally

-Fastboot says "waiting for device"... forever.

-(Did not try fastboot devices in windows.)

In Linux:

-Fastboot can NEVER find the device.

-ADB can only find the device when it is on normally

'lsusb' looks like this when the device is turned on normally:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0480:a007 Toshiba America Inc External Disk USB 3.0
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c404 Logitech, Inc. TrackMan Wheel
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 076: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

But looks like this with the bootloader screen on the phone:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0480:a007 Toshiba America Inc External Disk USB 3.0
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c404 Logitech, Inc. TrackMan Wheel
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Thanks for any help, I'm really running out of things to try here.  (Could I still get to the bootloader screen if it were locked?)

Comment: What does the Device Manager show in Windows?  Is there a device with an error?

Comment: It appears normally in device driver when booted.  It displays nothing that I can find to associate with the phone when it is in download mode.

Comment: Oh wait, hang on, we're talking about a Galaxy S device.  They don't have fastboot mode, they have Download Mode.  What version of Odin are you using?  Have you tried Heimdall?

Comment: Heimdall can't find it either.  I figured out I need to use 3.10, that can at least download stuff... not that I've managed to install safestrap yet...

Comment: It kind of sounds like the device isn't working properly while in download mode.  Not sure how to fix that!

Comment: I had the same conclusion.. *BUT* if you use the right version of Odin you can put some stock stuff on there.  I'm following an update process that flashes a stock root which updates, and then you can use towel root on.... I'll let you know if it works, thanks for the help.